# different results query vs filter

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have a simple query with a SELECT a.Field from DE  WHERE a.Field NOT LIKE '%Control%' and I'm getting a different number than when I filter the same data extension with the filter not contain 'Control'. Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried to refresh the filtered DE?

Comment: Is there differences in primary keys? Duplicates? etc.?  I would check the context and environment to see if there is something there that is causing the discrepancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the field had some records empty and with the filter those records where counted but with the  WHERE a.Field NOT LIKE '%Control%' those empty fields where excluded

Comment: Remember to accept your own answer, so the question is not listed as unanswered